# mongo replicated shard member not able to recover, stuck in STARTUP2 mode

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have following setup for a sharded replica set in Amazon VPC:

mongo1:   8G RAM Duo core  (Primary)

mongo2:   8G RAM Duo core  (Secondary)

mongo3:   4G RAM  (Arbiter)

mongo1 is the primary member in the replica set with a 2 shard setup:

```
 mongod --port 27000 --dbpath /mongo/config -- configsvr 

 mongod --port 27001 --dbpath /mongo/shard1 --shardsvr --replSet rssh1

 mongod --port 27002 --dbpath /mongo/shard2 --shardsvr --replSet rssh2
```

Mongo2 is the secondary member in the replica set, mirrors mongo1 exactly:

```
 mongod --port 27000 --dbpath /mongo/config -- configsvr 

 mongod --port 27001 --dbpath /mongo/shard1 --shardsvr --replSet rssh1   # Faulty process

 mongod --port 27002 --dbpath /mongo/shard2 --shardsvr --replSet rssh2
```

Then for some reason, the 27001 process on mongo2 experienced a crash due to out of memory (cause unknown) last week. When I discovered the issue (the application still works getting data from the primary) and restarted the 27001 process, it was too late to catch up with the shard1 on mongo1. So I followed 10gen's recommendation:

- emptied directory /mongo/shard1
- restart the 27001 process using command

  ```
  mongod --port 27001 --dbpath /mongo/shard1 --shardsvr --replSet rssh1
  ```

However it's 24+ hours now, the node is still in `STARTUP2` mode, I have about 200G data in the `shard1` and it appears that it got about 160G over to `/mongo/shard1` on mongo2. Following is the replica set status command output(run on `mongo2`)

```
rssh1:STARTUP2> rs.status()
{
     "set" : "rssh1",
     "date" : ISODate("2012-10-29T19:28:49Z"),
     "myState" : 5,
     "syncingTo" : "mongo1:27001",
     "members" : [
          {
               "_id" : 1,
               "name" : "mongo1:27001",
               "health" : 1,
               "state" : 1,
               "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
               "uptime" : 99508,
               "optime" : Timestamp(1351538896000, 3),
               "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-10-29T19:28:16Z"),
               "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-10-29T19:28:48Z"),
               "pingMs" : 0
          },
          {
               "_id" : 2,
               "name" : "mongo2:27001",
               "health" : 1,
               "state" : 5,
               "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
               "uptime" : 99598,
               "optime" : Timestamp(1351442134000, 1),
               "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-10-28T16:35:34Z"),
               "self" : true
          },
          {
               "_id" : 3,  
               "name" : "mongoa:27901",
               "health" : 1,
               "state" : 7,
               "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
               "uptime" : 99508,
               "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-10-29T19:28:48Z"),
               "pingMs" : 0
          }
     ],
     "ok" : 1
}

rssh1:STARTUP2>
```

It would appear most of the data from primary was replicated, but not all.  The logs shows some error but I don't know if it's related:

```
Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] assertion 13436 not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member ns:config.system.indexes query:{ expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] problem detected during query over config.system.indexes : { $err: "not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member", code: 13436 }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] ERROR: error processing ttl for db: config 10065 invalid parameter: expected an object ()

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] assertion 13436 not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member ns:gf2.system.indexes query:{ expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] problem detected during query over gf2.system.indexes : { $err: "not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member", code: 13436 }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] ERROR: error processing ttl for db: gf2 10065 invalid parameter: expected an object ()

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] assertion 13436 not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member ns:kombu_default.system.indexes query:{ expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] problem detected during query over kombu_default.system.indexes : { $err: "not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member", code: 13436 }

Mon Oct 29 19:39:59 [TTLMonitor] ERROR: error processing ttl for db: kombu_default 10065 invalid parameter: expected an object ()
```

Everything on primary appeared to be fine. No errors in the log.

I tried the steps twice, one with the mongo config server running and one with mongo config server down, both are same results.

This is a production setup and I really need to get the replica set back up working, any help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard to diagnose without the full logs, but the easiest way to get that secondary back to normal is to resync it from scratch from the primary.  Basically stop that mongod, delete all data in the dbpath (including subdirectories), then restart.  It will kick off the sync process as if it were a new member.

For what it's worth, running two full instances (primary/secondary) on what sound like m1.large instances is probably going to see a lot of resource contention, especially on the disk side of things.

In terms of the crash, based on the limited evidence, it could be the OOM Killer at work:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/The+Linux+Out+of+Memory+OOM+Killer

To avoid it, make sure you have some swap space configured.

Answer (score 0):

if you run on mongo2

```
db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
```

what do you see ?

Also what you can do is to remove the mongo2 from the replica set - delete all data from mongo2 and re-add it.

```
rs.remove("mongo2:27001")
rs.add("mongo2:27001")
rs.status()
```